# Almost sure convergence of randomvariables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have the following to solve and I think I almost solved, however I am not able to make the last step.

Let $(X_{n})_{n\geq1}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables on the same probability space with a continuous distribution function. Show that for $n \rightarrow \infty$: $$\frac{|\left \{ i \leq n : X_{2i-1}>X_{2i} \right \}|}{n}\overset{a.s.}{\rightarrow}\frac{1}{2}$$

What I have done so far:
I think that this can be solved using the law of large numbers. So i defined:
$$Y_{i} = \left\{\begin{matrix}
1, & X_{2i-1}>X_{2i} \\ 
0, & else
\end{matrix}\right.$$
Obviously, the $Y_{i}$ are i.i.d. and $E[Y_{1}]<\infty$.
So I can use the law of large numbers and the following follows:
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_{i}\overset{a.s.}{\rightarrow}E[Y_{1}]$$.
The sum is the same as the cardinality of the set above.

**So what I have to show additionally is that $E[Y_{1}]=\frac{1}{2}$.** How do I do that? Could someone give me a hint?

Thanks for your help and have a great day

Comment: Since $X_1$ and $X_2$ are i.i.d., what do you know about $\mathbb{P}(X_1 - X_2 > 0 )$?

Comment: And what do you know about the distribution of $X_1 - X_2$ and $X_2 - X_1$?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Do I know that X1-X2 and X2-X1 are i.i.d.? I don't really get it.

Comment: They are not independent, since $X_1 - X_2 > 0 $ implies $X_2 - X_1 < 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $\mathbb{P}(X_1 >X_2 ) > \mathbb{P}(X_2 > X_1)$.
However, since $X_1$ and $X_2$ are i.i.d., we can interchange the indices $1$ and $2$, which yields the inequality $\mathbb{P}( X_2 > X_1) > \mathbb{P}(X_1 > X_2)$.
Combining those inequalities we get
$$\mathbb{P}(X_1 > X_ 2) > \mathbb{P}( X_2 > X_1) > \mathbb{P}(X_1 > X_2) \implies \mathbb{P}(X_1 > X_2) > \mathbb{P}(X_1 > X_2).$$
This is absurd, and therefore we have $\mathbb{P}(X_1 > X_2) = \mathbb{P}(X_2> X_1)$.

Since \begin{eqnarray}
1 &=& \mathbb{P}( (X_1 > X_2) \cup (X_2 > X_1) \cup (X_1 = X_2)) \\
&=& \mathbb{P} (X_1 > X_2) + \mathbb{P}(X_2 > X_1) +\mathbb{P}(X_1 = X_2) \\
&=& \mathbb{P}(X_1 = X_2) + 2 \mathbb{P}(X_1 > X_2)
\end{eqnarray}
So if you can argue $\mathbb{P}(X_1 = X_2) = 0$ (which holds by continuity of the distribution), you are done.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this makes it clear. I had similar ideas, however I was not sure whether i.i.d. allows me to interchange the indices and I failed to proof that it's possible.